# How do I implement an AVL tree in java? Why does compareTo say source unknown?

Tags: java, eclipse, tree, javadoc, compareto

I am working on implementing an AVL tree for a project for class. I've written my search and insert methods but I am not sure if it works. When I try to test my search and insert, everytime my search method in my program reaches my compareTo statement, it gives a null pointer exception. I know that search works only if there is one item, the root, and it returns true. But it seems like the root's left/right child are not linked. When I insert multiple integers and search for them, it doesn't do anything, or it always returns true.

How do I implement an AVL tree? Do I HAVE to use a linked list/arraylist? Is is possible to implement it without using any of these. Part of the requirement is that I must NOT use anything from the JCF. I have spent countless hours trying to figure out what is wrong and I always get back to first base.

When I use .compareTo, it tells me source is unknown. Example test run:

Is the tree empty false
Size of tree: 2
testing left height
Height of tree: 2
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Unknown Source)
    at AVLTree.search(AVLTree.java:110)
    at AVLTreeTest.main(AVLTreeTest.java:13)

Main test program:

```
    public class AVLTreeTest {
        public static void main(String args[]){
            AVLTree<Integer> tree = new AVLTree<Integer>();

            tree.insert(9);
            //tree.insert(5);
            tree.insert(4);
            //tree.insert(3);
            //tree.insert(19);
            System.out.println("Is the tree empty " + tree.isEmpty());
            System.out.println("Size of tree: " + tree.size());
            System.out.println("Height of tree: " + tree.height());
            System.out.println(tree.search(9));
            System.out.println(tree.search(5));
        }
    }
```

When I press f2 on my compareTo line:

```
    else if(root!=null && item.compareTo(root.getItem())==0){
```

The following pops up:

Open Declaration: int java.lang.Comparable.compareTo(T arg0)
Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why does it say unknown source for my compareTo line?  It shows: int java.lang.Comparable.compareTo(T arg0) Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.

Comment: I also wanted to know if I can implement an AVL tree without using a linked list or array list, but I figured that out.

Comment: You probably don't need to inspect the code for the jdk.  If you really want the source for the jdk, you can download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and attach it to the jdk instance in eclipse.  Note, you can also just add the url for the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html) to view javadoc for the jdk in eclipse.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out with the help of my schools tutor. I had two tiny and silly fixes I had to make to my code. I need more sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer.compareTo` throws a `NullPointerException` if you pass `null` into it. Given your code, it looks like `root.getItem()` returned `null`.

"Unknown Source" in the stack trace means that information about the source code was not available. In any case you can be pretty sure the problem is not in the `Integer` standard class, so you should look at the first trace entry coming from your code. That would be AVLTree.java at line 110.

Comment: Thank you. the item I was comparing to was null. Campus tutor helped me find out that my constructor was not initializing my "item". All I had to do was add this.item=item and remove an unnecessary return statement in a while loop in my search method that kept kicking me out regardless if the search was true. These tiny mistakes will be the death of me.